# PHP update multiple rows on submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-update

Hi I have echoed out multiple rows from a database. Each row has a select box which echoes out what is currently in that field related to that row.

With the select box I can select a different option. On submit nothing is happening, no errors. What it should do is update those fields. I have never managed to update multiple rows before so this is new to me.

The first query below is the update I'm trying to achieve to update all the fields with order_ref

The second query just echoes out all the data required to view.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
?>
    <form>
    <table class="tbl-qa">  
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th class="table-header"><p>Action</p></th>
                    <th class="table-header"><p>Campaign</p></th>
                    <th class="table-header"><p>Title</p></th>
                    <th class="table-header" width="100px"><p>Order Reference</p></th>
                    <th class="table-header"><p>Last updated</p></th>
                  </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
    <?php
        require_once("../db/db_connection.php");
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {      
            $sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE articles SET order_ref=? WHERE id=?
            ");
            $order_ref = $_POST['order_ref'];

            $sql->bind_param("ii", $order_ref, $_GET["id"]);    
            if($sql->execute()) {
                $success_message = "Edited Successfully";
            } else {
                $error_message = "Problem in Editing Record";
            }
        }
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE campname=? ORDER BY order_ref ASC

    ");
        $sql->bind_param("s",$_GET["campname"]);            
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->get_result();
    ?>

    <?php
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                ?>  

                <tr>
                    <td class="table-row" width="100px"><div class="edit"><a href="/_admin/edit.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="link">Edit</a> |</div><div class="bin"><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="link"><img content="delete" id="delete" title="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" src="/_admin/images/delete.png"/></div>
                    </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row["campname"]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-row"><a href="../campaigns/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row["campname"])); ?>/page.php?art_url=<?php echo $row["art_url"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["art_title"]; ?></a></td>
                    <td class="contentedit">
                    <select name="order_ref">
                    <option value="<?php echo $row["order_ref"]?>"selected><?php echo $row["order_ref"]?></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                    <td class="table-row"><?php echo strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["last_updated"])); ?></a></td>
                    <!-- action -->
                    </tr>
                <?php

                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        echo "No results";
                    }

                ?>
                                <tr class="table-row">
                    <td colspan="5"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" class="submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </form>
```

What do I need to do in order to update order_ref for every row that's echoed out?

Comment: please post the html / form for this.

Comment: You're using both POST and GETs here, why? `$order_ref = $_POST['order_ref'];` and `$order_ref, $_GET["id"])`, which one is it?

Comment: *"no errors"* - I see no error handling whatsoever.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I have included the form code and error handling. Hope this gives you a better idea.

Comment: Forms default to GET with no POST method. You have error reporting but didn't tell us what errors you got back. `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` will not happen. Same for `$order_ref = $_POST['order_ref'];`.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I have added full code with error reporting code at the top. I'm getting from link from a page before to display the results. The POST is to update the rows. Sounds like I'm not doing this correctly.

Comment: Still no solution for this one